# How does a server recognize a clients purchase?

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, client-server

I have a webserver as a game server which will respond on https requests.
For example the user can click on an item in shop with ingame currency.
Then the request will be send from Client -> Server: */buyitem?playerID=1234&itemID=10*

Then the server can check if the user is allowed to buy that item (for example has enough resource, itemID is valid...)

But how does it work when there is payment done on client side?
If a user buy 500 Gold for 0.99$ it is executed on client side and afterwards there will be a request Client->Server: */buyGold?playerID=1234&count=500*

How can the server now verify that this is a valid request and that the client really bought it with his money and is NOT sending this request on it's own without having bought it before??

Thank you!

Comment: Pass the transaction to the payment processor, and confirm with the payment processor that the transaction has been completed?

Comment: When you say: `is NOT sending this request on it's own without having bought it before` you are saying that the user cannot buy same product twice?

Comment: No I mean that the user can not "break" the apk and detect the call that has to be made for getting gold from the server /buyGold?playerID=1234&count=500 which should be only called when the transaction is successful

Comment: As Matheen mentioned: Usually this is done via a third party and the server forwards the request and doesn't do anything until it gets the go from the payment instance back.